# My activity can't implement lifecycleOwner

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I am using android studio,and the dependencies in build.gradle is here

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

and here is the function i'm using

```
private Single<MediaStream> getMediaStream() {
    Single<MediaStream> single = RxHelper.single(MediaStream.
            getBindedMediaStream(this, this), mediaStream);
    if (mediaStream == null) {
        return single.doOnSuccess(new Consumer<MediaStream>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(MediaStream ms) throws Exception {
                mediaStream = ms;
            }
        });
    } else {
        return single;
    }
}
```

here is the getBinderMediaStream:

```
public static Publisher<MediaStream> getBindedMediaStream(
        final Context context, LifecycleOwner owner){
    final MediaStreamPublisher publisher = new MediaStreamPublisher(context, owner);
    return publisher;
}
```

the error is: wrong 2nd argument type.Found:'com.example.mtTest.testActivity', required :'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner'.

please help me

Comment: extend your activity with AppCompatActivity

Comment: in this line getBindedMediaStream(this, this) , u r passing 2 context args , give a LifecycleOwner obj as second arg , check the code

Comment: @android_jain I already extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Vinay Sasalatti, i learned that in the latest appcompatactivity, it should implement lifecycleowner

Comment: What if I don't want to extends AppCompatActivity? I want to use Activity directly by implementing LifecycleOwner :(

Comment: thanks guys, the problem is solved. when i import a module, it mix up my gradle setting. I've changed it. so it works