# android activity doesn't recognize my import

Tags: android, import, module, appcompatactivity

this question is related to this one. [My activity can't implement lifecycleOwner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49812582/9608562) 
I suppose this question may contains the answer of lifecycleOwner one. 
I find this answer
[AppCompatActivity not implementing LifecycleOwner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46465056/9608562)  but it didn't solve my problem

I'm doing an android project in android. In every activity, it just doesn't recognize my imports.
like this:

```
private EditText edAccount;
edAccount = findViewById(R.id.edAccount);
```

it says: required: `android.widget.EditText Found:android.view.View`
But I do `imports android.widget.EditText`. This happened after i import a new library module. But i don't know what's going on.

Also, the AppCompatActivity doesn't implement lifecycleOwner anymore.

Thank you for your answer

the build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.finaldesigntest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    productFlavors {
    }
}


repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

repositories {
    flatDir { dirs project(':library').file('libs') }
//    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //jcenter()
        //maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.contrarywind:Android-PickerView:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation project(':library')
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
}
```

this is activity's layout.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.finaldesigntest.LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Account: "/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/edAccount"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Password: "/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/edPassword"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/remember_pass"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Remember password"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:text="Login"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view_login_result"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `edAccount = (Edittext)findViewById(R.id.edAccount);`

Comment: cast view to edittext, **like in Hemant's comment**

Comment: I think caps matter, so EditText

Comment: It doesn't happen in the first place. I want to know how to make it back to the old way. then I may solve my lifecycleOwner problem. Thx

Comment: Please expand the question with relevant .xml and build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: @Gotiasits, I pasted my build.gradle, please take a look

Comment: ...and layout .xml containing `edAccount`

Comment: @Gotiasits,  it happens to every activity.

Comment: You probably have name coalison. I had a similar problem with multi-library projects. Rename .xml files to be unique in across all modules. Also I do not see `edAccount` in posted .xml

Comment: sorry, I got the wrong xml, now I changed it.  But all my .xml names are unique. @Gotiasits

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you build your project successfully. it only happen when gradle build is not success.

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: It was a successful project until I import a module library. then this happen

Comment: after adding your library in your project, is build success.? @xiLianPeng

Comment: the issue happens after the import module so not success @PrashantJajal

Comment: may be your imported module have some configuration error. can you please add some `Gradle Log` in question for better idea.

Comment: the imported module is a ok. what's gradle log by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it like this:

```
 private EditText edAccount;
 edAccount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAccount);
```

Comment: I know it works, but i wanna know why it suddenly went wrong. I hope to know the reason to solve this one. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49812582/9608562